# Pandas sum up to a specific column value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, typeerror

The little piece of code is giving me more trouble than necessary.  I would appreciate any help if I could.  Thank you in advance for taking a look at this for me.

I am trying to sum up the price and the volume from the previous 22 data points which I added a column  named dtt that holds this value.  
The formula that I am trying to represent here is:

```
vamp = [sum(1, dtt) price * volume] / [sum(1,dtt) volume]
```

Here is my code

```
# Import necessary libraries
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import os

# Load SPY dataset
spy_data = pd.read_csv('SPY.csv', parse_dates=['Date'])
# Compute Daily Return
spy_data['daily_ret'] = (spy_data['Adj Close'] - (spy_data['Adj Close']).shift(1)) / ((spy_data['Adj Close']).shift(1)) * 100
spy_data['daily_ret'] = spy_data['daily_ret'].fillna(0.0)

# calculate Annualized Volatility
rsquare = (spy_data['daily_ret']) ** 2
spy_data['annualized_volatility']=(np.sqrt(rsquare.rolling(252).sum() / 251) * np.sqrt(252))
spy_data['annualized_volatility'] = spy_data['annualized_volatility'].fillna(0)

spy_shares = 889112600

# Calculate Days to Trade
spy_data['dtt'] = spy_shares / (spy_data['Volume'].rolling(22).sum()/22)
spy_data['dtt'] = spy_data['dtt'].fillna(1).astype(int)

# Calculate VWAP
#numerator is equal to the sum of the price * volume of the latest DTT
numerator = spy_data.loc[0:spy_data['dtt'], 'Adj Close'].sum()#*spy_data.loc[0:spy_data['dtt'], 'Volume']
#denominator = spy_data.loc[0:spy_data['dtt'], 'Volume']
#spy_data['vwap'] = numerator / denominator
print(spy_data)
```

I commented out the other lines because I was trying to problem solve it one step at a time.  The price column that I need is the `Adj Close`.

No matter what I try in terms of slicing I keep getting an error. This is the current one:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-68-ade975138e12> in <module>
      7 # Calculate VWAP
      8 #numerator is equal to the sum of the price * volume of the latest DTT
----> 9 numerator = spy_data.loc[0:spy_data['dtt']].sum()#*spy_data[0:spy_data['dtt'], 'volume']
     10 #denominator = spy_data.loc[0:spy_data['dtt'], 'Volume']
     11 #spy_data['vwap'] = numerator / denominator

~/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py in __getitem__(self, key)
   1408 
   1409             maybe_callable = com.apply_if_callable(key, self.obj)
-> 1410             return self._getitem_axis(maybe_callable, axis=axis)
   1411 
   1412     def _is_scalar_access(self, key: Tuple):

~/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py in _getitem_axis(self, key, axis)
   1770         if isinstance(key, slice):
   1771             self._validate_key(key, axis)
-> 1772             return self._get_slice_axis(key, axis=axis)
   1773         elif com.is_bool_indexer(key):
   1774             return self._getbool_axis(key, axis=axis)

~/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py in _get_slice_axis(self, slice_obj, axis)
   1438         labels = obj._get_axis(axis)
   1439         indexer = labels.slice_indexer(
-> 1440             slice_obj.start, slice_obj.stop, slice_obj.step, kind=self.name
   1441         )
   1442 

~/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py in slice_indexer(self, start, end, step, kind)
   5025         slice(1, 3)
   5026         """
-> 5027         start_slice, end_slice = self.slice_locs(start, end, step=step, kind=kind)
   5028 
   5029         # return a slice

~/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py in slice_locs(self, start, end, step, kind)
  5245         end_slice = None
  5246         if end is not None:
   -> 5247             end_slice = self.get_slice_bound(end, "right", kind)
  5248         if end_slice is None:
  5249             end_slice = len(self)

~/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py in get_slice_bound(self, label, side, kind)
  5155         # we need to look up the label
  5156         try:
   -> 5157             slc = self.get_loc(label)
  5158         except KeyError as err:
  5159             try:

~/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/range.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   377             except ValueError:
   378                 raise KeyError(key)
   --> 379         return super().get_loc(key, method=method, tolerance=tolerance)
   380 
   381     @Appender(_index_shared_docs["get_indexer"])

~/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
  2888                 )
  2889             try:
   -> 2890                 return self._engine.get_loc(key)
  2891             except KeyError:
  2892                 return self._engine.get_loc(self._maybe_cast_indexer(key))

pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

TypeError: '0        1
 1        1
 2        1
 3        1
 4        1
    ..
 4694     9
 4695     9
 4696    10
 4697    10
 4698    11
 Name: dtt, Length: 4699, dtype: int64' is an invalid key
```

Comment: Your provided code is not runable.

Comment: What do you mean by loc of `0:spy_data['dtt']`?

Comment: well the formula is to sum up to the latest dtt value, so I thought I needed to select that value from the dtt column.  So for the first calculation it would be from 0 to the dtt found at spy_data['dtt'].